# Why is MySQL Replication so complicated?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

It seems so simple: I have two servers running MySQL, one has a nice big database of important stuff, the other is an empty shell ready to be used as a replication slave. These are the steps I *should* need to take to set up replication:

1. Add a user to the master with the relevent replication & host privileges
2. Run a statement from the slave telling it to 'replicate this db from this server'
3. Done. That's it.

Instead I have to mess around with my.cnf settings on both servers, mess about with binary logs and positions and snapshots. Yes I know some of these things are optimisations for large databases but is this the *best* way they could think of doing this? I just want to replicate a database, this is a very common practice. I still have not managed it.

Where can I find a decent how-to for this? Everything I've found so-far is either missing some important step, is written for an older version of MySQL or is just plain too complex for me or requires a degree of commitment I'm clearly not prepared to take, and that includes the official documentation.

Comment: Please watch your language.

Comment: Sorry, MySQL makes me angry

Comment: Have you considered other DB engines, careers or counselling?

Comment: @chaopper3 - awesome edit of the original post. +1

Comment: @jimmy - go away and vent your anger elsewhere. Come back when you have something specific we can help you with. -1

Comment: @coops, whatever frames the question most accurately eh :)

Comment: If I could give rep for edits I would. :)

Comment: I'm here all week, try the chicken :)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication

Answer (score 1):

I bought the book titled "High Performance MySQL" by Schwartz, Zaitsev, Tkachenko, et al.

I have also used Slony on PostgreSQL. Wasn't straightforward, either.

Master-master replication seems a good idea.